# Error while booting the system ignoring bad line starting with '“blackist' on Ubuntu 18.4

Tags: wireless, realtek

When booting the system the error will displayed on the screen,

```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf line 1: ignoring bad line starting with '“options'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8xxxu.conf line 1: ignoring bad line starting with 'blackist'
```

I am trying to install the wifi driver this issue happens. How do I fix this issue and install the wifi driver to my computer?

When I do `ls /etc/modprobe.d`,
[image]

Comment: Try to look at the content of the two files mentioned, and look up the correct syntax. Eventually update your question with the content of the two files.

Comment: @SorenA No such files found

Comment: are you looking at `/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` and `/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8xxxu.conf` ?

Comment: @SorenA Yes....

Comment: Please edit your question to show the results of the terminal commands: `cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf ` and also: `cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8xxxu.conf ` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 "cat: /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf: No such file or directory"  - This is the message

Comment: Please post: `ls /etc/modprobe.d`

Comment: Please reboot. As you no longer have the referenced files, the error should no longer occur.